# Calculating the expected cost of bumping passengers from overbooked flights

Tags: probability, intuition

This question is related to this [TED video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZFNstNKgEDI) which shows a particularly interesting calculation of bumping passengers from a overbooked flight. The actual segment of that video is [here](https://youtu.be/ZFNstNKgEDI?t=207).
[image]

The whole problem goes as follows: If there are 180 seats in an airplane what is the optimal number of tickets that the airline can sell that will yield the maximum revenue.

Now lets say each ticket costs 250 dollars and every bumped passenger must be paid 800 dollars as compensation. What is the optimal number of tickets the airline can sell ?

**Now they offer a sample calculation of the expected returns for selling a 195 tickets. It is this calculation I am unable to understand.**

It says the calculation is done via:

```
Expected value of 195 tickets = p(181) * 1 * 800 + p(182) * 2 * 800 + ..so on
```

**My first question** is why multiply the probability value with the cost ? What does it even mean : `2 * 800 * p(182)` ? What does it even mean ? This calculation makes absolutely no sense to me.

**My second question**, is that why would you add up all the probability and cost multiplications ? I mean how does adding those up give you the expected value for selling 195 tickets.

I have no idea how this calculation even makes sense.

Comment: The goal is to **maximize the revenue**. Let's start by assuming that the airline indeed sells more tickets than there are seats. But then the unknown parameter is **how many people show up** out of those for whom the tickets were sold. Revenue in this case is calculated as
$$
\begin{split}
\text{Revenue} =& 250 \times \text{ # of tickets sold} \\ &- \underbrace{800 \times (\text{# of people who show up} - 180)}_{\text{compensation}}
\end{split}
$$
We don't know how many people will show up, and therefore the revenue is a random variable. The next step is to calculate its expected value.

Comment: The expected value of a random variable is calculated as the sum over the product of the **value of the variable**, times its probability. So in this case we can mark $X=\text{# of people who show up}$ (assume it's at least 180). Revenue $R$ is a function of $X$, $R=R(X)$. Then the expected value of revenue is
$$
\mathbb{E}[R] = R(180)P(X=180) + R(181)P(X=181) + R(181)P(X=181) + \ldots
$$
This comes just from the definition of expected value.

Comment: Is it clearer now? We haven't even discussed what the probabilities $P(X)$ could mean, but they are just some probabilities.

Comment: @MattiP. Yes it is clearer now. I now know that the expected value is nothing but a mean of a random variable. But I think you meant the compensation provided to be a random variable. Because that is what we are taking the expected value of. Not the revenue. **How can the revenue be a random variable ?**

Comment: Look at the definition of revenue. It's equal to the ticket sales minus the compensation. The ticket sales are assumed to be known, but the compensation is a random variable. Therefore, the revenue is a random variable. Amazing, isn't it! :)

Comment: @MattiP. Yes it is. You might want to put all this into an answer. Thanks.